# Textbox not clicked in TinyMCE modal box

Tags: modal-dialog, tinymce

`TinyMCE` (Dev build) image `textbox` not clickable in modal with bootstrap theme. 
Any modal textboxes are not clickable.

Please help check - we use the below code:

```
$(document).on('focusin',function(e){
    if($(event.target).closest(".mce-window").length){
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi dheeru, welcome to StackOverflow! It would help us help you if you could provide an example via jsfiddle.net or place the associated HTML in your post?

Comment: Html 
<div class="form-group">
                   <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%"></textarea>
                  </div>
js
tinymce.dev.js

javascript added end of statement.
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});

Comment: in normal condition it's working fine but when we use editor in modal bootstrap pop up text box disable for editing